# Filter table to show only most recent values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that looks like this.

| Category | Type | fromDate | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1/1/2022 | 5 |
| 1 | 2 | 1/1/2022 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 1/1/2022 | 7.5 |
| 2 | 2 | 1/1/2022 | 15 |
| 3 | 1 | 1/1/2022 | 3.5 |
| 3 | 2 | 1/1/2022 | 5 |
| 3 | 1 | 4/1/2022 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 4/1/2022 | 10 |

I'm trying to filter this table down to filter down and keep the most recent grouping of Category/Type. IE rows 5 and 6 would be removed in the query since they are older records.

So far I have the below query but I am getting an aggregate error due to not aggregating the "Value" column. My question is how do I get around this without aggregating? I want to keep the actual value that is in the column.

```
    SELECT T1.Category, T1.Type, T2.maxDate, T1.Value 
    FROM (SELECT Category, Type, MAX(fromDate) AS maxDate 
            FROM Table GROUP BY Category,Type) T2
    INNER JOIN Table T1 ON T1.Category=T2.Category
    GROUP BY T1.Category, T1.Type, T2.MaxDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been asked and answered dozens and dozens of times. But it was quick and painless to type up an answer. This should work for you.

```
declare @MyTable table
(
    Category int
    , Type int
    , fromDate date
    , Value decimal(5,2)
)

insert @MyTable
select 1, 1, '1/1/2022', 5 union all
select 1, 2, '1/1/2022', 10 union all
select 2, 1, '1/1/2022', 7.5 union all
select 2, 2, '1/1/2022', 15 union all
select 3, 1, '1/1/2022', 3.5 union all
select 3, 2, '1/1/2022', 5 union all
select 3, 1, '4/1/2022', 5 union all
select 3, 2, '4/1/2022', 10

select Category
    , Type
    , fromDate
    , Value
from
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Category, Type order by fromDate desc)
    from @MyTable
) x
where x.RowNum = 1
order by x.Category
    , x.Type
```